# Remove belongs_to relation from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, database-migration

I want to remove `User` `belongs_to` relation from customised dresses table.

This is my customised dress migration:

```
class CreateCustomisedDresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :customised_dresses do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true, null: :false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :customised_dresses, :users, dependent: :delete
end
```

I tried by below migration but it gives me an error:

```
class RemoveForeignKeyUsersFromCustomisedDresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_foreign_key :customised_dresses, :users
  end
  def self.down
    remove_foreign_key :customised_dresses, :users
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should exchange your code in up and down methods:

```
class RemoveForeignKeyUsersFromCustomisedDresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    remove_foreign_key :customised_dresses, :users
  end
  def self.down
    add_foreign_key :customised_dresses, :users
  end
end
```